# I fail to create a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write some PHP code that can list artists on the left of the page (success)
but i fail at using that array of artists to find their songs and display on the right side of the page.
The song names are formated like this: "(Artist) - (Song).mp3"
Heres my code:

```
<?php
// integer starts at 0 before counting
$dir = 'songs/';
$i = 0;
$artistExplode = array();
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
$artists = array();
while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
    if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
        $artistExplode[$i] = explode(" - ",$file);
        $artist = @$artistExplode[$i][0];
        if(!in_array($artist, $artists)) {
            $artists[$i] = $artist;
            $i++;
        }
}
}
$x = $i;
$i = 0;
$songs = 0;
while($x !== 1){
$i++;
$songs++;
if($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
        if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) {
            //echo $file."<hr />";
            $songs++;
            $artists[$i][$songs] = $file;
        }
    }
}
    $artists[$i];
$x--;
}
print_r($artists);
```

I've done some research and dont understand how those random characters in array come from, I expected the song names to come in a sub array for each artist

Here's the output of the print_r()

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => 2 2DEEHKMTTT [2] => DVBBS & Borge2DEEHKMTTT [3] => Eminem 2DEEHKMTTT [4] => Hardwell & Dyro 2DEEHKMTTT [5] => Kanye West & Jay Z 2DEEHKMTTT [6] => Martin Garrix 2DEEHKMTTT [7] => TryHardNinja 2DEEHKMTTT )
```

Comment: How are you "failing"?  What does the `print_r` show?

Comment: The print_r shows "Array ( [0] => [1] => 2 2DEEHKMTTT [2] => DVBBS & Borge2DEEHKMTTT [3] => Eminem 2DEEHKMTTT [4] => Hardwell & Dyro 2DEEHKMTTT [5] => Kanye West & Jay Z 2DEEHKMTTT [6] => Martin Garrix 2DEEHKMTTT [7] => TryHardNinja 2DEEHKMTTT )"
I have no idea where those random characters come from

Comment: What result you want to reach. Can you show example ?

Comment: Let's say i have a song named "Eminem - Survival.mp3" in the "songs" folder. I want to be able to get all the artist names from the song names (succeeded). I store those artist names in an array and try to read the folder again to use the artist names to get the songs. On the left side of the page i want all the artist names and when i click them i want to display the songs to the right.

Comment: Then you need two blocks of code one that lists artists (you have) and second to list songs by artist. Now it's clear.

Comment: I don't recommend doing this, because the names of your files aren't guaranteed. Use file metadata if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like this (untested):

```
<?php
// integer starts at 0 before counting
$dir = 'songs/';
$i = 0;
$artistExplode = array();
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
$artists = array();
while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
    if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) {
        $artistExplode = explode(" - ",$file);
        $artist = (string)trim($artistExplode[0]);
        $song=(string)trim($artistExplode[1]);

        if($artist<>'' && $song<>'') {
            $artists[$artist][]=$song;
        }
    }
}
}
print_r($artists);
?>
```

Comment: This one worked really well, Thank you so much for the awnser :)

Answer (score 1):

I made the following test:

```
        $music[] = "Eminem - Survival.mp3";
        $music[] = "Eminem - Survival2.mp3";
        $music[] = "Eminem - Survival3.mp3";
        $music[] = "Eminem - Survival4.mp3";
        $music[] = "Jay Z - Song.mp3";
        $music[] = "Jay Z - Song1.mp3";
        $music[] = "Jay Z - Song2.mp3";

        foreach($music as $mus)
        {
            $artist[] = explode("-",$mus);

        }

        $test = "Eminem";
        echo "Eminem Songs"."</br>";
        foreach($artist as $art)
        { 
          if(trim($art[0])==$test)
          {
              echo $art[1]."</br>";
          }
        }

        $test = "Jay Z";
        echo "Jay Z Songs"."</br>";
        foreach($artist as $art)
        { 
          if(trim($art[0])==$test)
          {
              echo $art[1]."</br>";
          }
        }
```

Working fiddle here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/n90-3td

Comment: Good suggestion but the accepted awnser was easier to put into my code in my opinion. But thanks for the awnser :)